# Dashboard For Mobile App

Tags: laravel, admin, panel, dashboard

I am building a native app in android / ios and using laravel 5.3 for server side API's development. This app is related to E-commerce where user and seller will come buy an sell their product. To browse all the users, products and other statistics and action I want to develop an admin / dashboard panel. What is the best way to do this.

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways to do it. You can use tokenized api from laravel for authentication and you can use jwt sort of libraries. Which will allow you to authenticate and with tokenized api you can securely make http request with your laravel back end. You just have to specify api guard specifically for your admin panel. There is one default api guard as well. You can use that one or create new. Completly upto you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this: https://asgardcms.com/. It's a modular multilingual CMS built with Laravel 5, with an MIT license.